# How can I get the ViewController instance starting from subView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I've an object of UIImageCustom that extend UIImageView, and in a method this class I want to get instance the ViewController, where my object UICustom is added.

In touchesBegan method of my class UIImageCustom, when I touch in UIImage, I want add other UIImage in my ViewController:

```
    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
    {
        UIImageView* newImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 200, 200, 200)];

        //Here I need add newImageView in my ViewController
        [??? addSubview:newImageView];
    }
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Why are not implementing touchesBegan in ViewController itself  ?

Comment: Hi @Bhumeshwerkatre!
I had implemented, but now I want use my UIImageCustom in others ViewControllers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways you could do this (set a custom property in your `UIImageCustom` class, just have `UIImageCustom` add this new image view to its own `superview` (e.g. `[self.superview addSubview:newImageView]`). But these approaches seem conceptually flawed. A view shouldn't be adding anything other than to itself (and if you turned off clipping, adding this new image view as a subview of the `UIImageCustom`, itself, might be another approach, certainly less offensive than the previous two I alluded to).

But I might suggest a couple of other approaches:

1. If your goal is simply to avoid duplication of your touches code, I might put it in a gesture recognizer subclass, rather than attaching it to some random `UIImageView` subclass. Gesture recognizers is the right place to put this sort of touch-related code. See the [Gesture Recognizers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW2) section of the *Event Handling Guide for iOS.*
2. Or if you really need to marry this gesture with with a bunch of image views, I might use a custom container view controller to mediate this interaction between gestures and image views. See [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) in the *View Controller Programming Guide* for more information.

   But you could wrap the touches code and the handling of these two image views all within a view controller, and then use view controller containment to add that to an existing view controller.

We don't know enough about the particular design to suggest one over another, but those are a couple of ideas to pursue. Most likely, the custom gesture recognizer approach should be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to add a custom property to your UIImageCustom class that contains a reference to the owner view controller if you want to do what you're saying you want to do. But there's a better way.

What I suggest you should be doing is implementing touchesBegan in the view controller that owns the view, and performing any custom logic there.

Comment: Hi @Travis, I had implemented, but now I want use my UIImageCustom in others ViewControllers and I thought that would possible make in UIImageCustom for not duplicate code.

Comment: In that case, have you considered implementing the delegate pattern? Your custom view could declare a protocol and have a delegate property, and you could call back to the view controllers and tell them what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Create a category like this

```
@interface UIViewController (TOP_MODAL)
-(UIViewController*) topModalController;
@end

@implementation UIViewController (TOP_MODAL)
-(UIViewController*) topModalController{
    if (self.presentedViewController == nil){
        return self;
    }
    return self.presentedViewController.topModalController;
}

@end
```

then

```
AppDelegate* delegate =  (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIViewController* viewController = [delegate.window.rootViewController topModalController];
...
[viewController.view addSubview:newImageView];
```